# How to decrypt SQLCipher database when sqlcipher_export fails

Tags: sqlite, encryption, sqlcipher

I'm trying to decrypt the SQLCipher database to look into it with the viewer app, buy when I use the command line tool to do as said [in here](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-api/index.html#sqlcipher_export):

```
>sqlcipher encrypted.db
sqlite> pragma key = 'key';
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'plaintext.db' AS plaintext KEY '';
sqlite> SELECT sqlcipher_export('plaintext');
```

I get the error:

```
Error: no such collation sequence: COLLATION_NAME
```

And the plaintext.db only has one empty table.

Is there any other way to decrypt the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, SQLite has the handy backup capability outlined here: https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html

And you can use this in the command line tool with the `.backup` special command (see help here: https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html). Which does work in the sqlcipher command line tool and produces the unencrypted database as a result.

Here's how to decrypt the database:

```
>sqlcipher encrypted.db
sqlite> pragma key = 'key';
sqlite> .backup plaintext.db
```

Of course, you can also do it programmatically by loading the database and using the backup APIs found at the first link (scroll to "Example 2: Online Backup of a Running Database" section), but I didn't explore this option.

Answer (score 0):

Was you database generated on the Android platform?  If so, it may be using a collation sourced from ICU, which is linked into SQLCipher for Android.  The basic build [instructions](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/introduction/) for the SQLCipher command line tool do not include steps for including ICU.  You may find it easier to perform a `sqlcipher_export(…)` on an Android device to take advantage of the presence of ICU.

Comment: It was generated on the Windows PC, but it's a good advice for the guys that did it on Android, thank you!